# print column and count the string

Tags: perl, awk

I have large column wise  text file with space demlimited

```
Name  subject       Result
John  maths         pass
John  science       fail
John  history       pass
John  geography     pass
Jack  maths         pass
jack  history       fail
kelly science       pass
kelly history       pass
```

I want to count for each name (it is long name list, each name should be appear only once), how many of them pass. For eg. For John, he passed 3 and similarily for Jack he passed 1. It should print the result as

```
Name  Passcount
John   3
Jack   1
Kelly  2
```

Can anybody can help with awk or perl script. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10921396/edit) link below your question to update it with the code you need advice with.  This is an easy problem to solve, but an incomplete question like this is likely to get closed before it gets answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
awk '
BEGIN{ print "Name\tPasscount"} 
NR>1{if ($3=="pass") a[$1]++}
END{ for (x in a) print x"\t"a[x]}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
Name  subject       Result
John  maths         pass
John  science       fail
John  history       pass
John  geography     pass
Jack  maths         pass
jack  history       fail
kelly science       pass
kelly history       pass

$ awk 'BEGIN{ print "Name\tPasscount"} NR>1{if ($3=="pass") a[$1]++}END{ for (x in a) print x"\t"a[x]}' file
Name    Passcount
Jack    1
kelly   2
John    3
```

Comment: You can also do `NR > 1 && $3 == "pass" {a[$1]++}`

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson … true that would be much cleaner than having clunky `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks Jayapal Singh..it worked well..but I need the output without changing name order..for eg Firstline should show John, followed by Jack and kelly